# using setInterval to increment variable every second - not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, increment

Inside my functional component I have defined two hooks `started:false` and `sec:0`

```
let interval = null
const Home = () =>  {
    const [sec, setSec] = useState(0)
    const [started, setStarted] = useState(false)
```

So as the name suggests, every second I want to increment this counter.
I have method called `setTimer` which should increment my `sec` every second.

```
function setTimer() {
  console.log(started)
  if (!started) {
    console.log(started)
    setStarted(true);
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSec(sec+1)
      console.log("ADDED",sec)
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

But it seems that the sec counter never goes above 1. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: do you call the setTimer function at all?

Comment: Yes I do. I have an input feild which whenever the value of that is changed, the function is called. And I clear the interval whenever a condition is met (length of the input == somevalue).

Comment: Make sure the started variable is false by default, the seconds variable is zero by default. Check that the setSec function takes an argument and sets the number of seconds to the function parameter, also make sure setStarted () enables a conditional statement.

Comment: I think it's because of using state, because you you don't know when the state is ready for another mutation, maybe the time `setSec` is called, the `sec` is still not changed. and `setSec` is called upon sec of 1. you must know that change of state does not occur synchronously. one solution is to not use state variables.

Comment: @nycaff yes by default started is false. and as shown in the example seconds is 0 at the start. All of the things you have said have been checked correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uses a functional state update, so instead of `setSec(sec+1)` write `setSec(prevSec => prevSec + 1)`

See the React Hooks API for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: Yes! This feels alot less hacky than the other given answers. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let started = false;
let sec = 0;

let setSec = function(seconds) { sec = seconds; }
let setStarted = function() { started = true; }

function setTimer() {
  console.log(started)
  if (!started) {
    setStarted(true);
    console.log(started)
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSec(sec+1)
      console.log("ADDED",sec)
    }, 1000)
  }
}

setTimer();
```

Comment: are all the variables and functions defined outside my functional component

Answer (score 0):

```js
var setStarted = false;
setSec = 0;
function setTimer() {
  console.log(setStarted)
  if (!setStarted) {
    console.log(setStarted)
    setStarted = true;
    setInterval(() => {
      setSec +=1;
      console.log("ADDED",setSec);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

setTimer();
```

Comment: are all the variables defined outside my functional component?

Comment: that would be the normal way to do things, check this out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

Answer (score 0):

setInterval has closed over the initial value of your state(sec). Every time you are modifiying it, you are doing setSec(0+1), essentially making it 1. This is the problem of stale state.

You can use useRef to have access to the current value always.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);
  const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

  let interval = null;
  let realSec = useRef(0);

  function setTimer() {
    console.log(started);
    if (!started) {
      console.log(started);
      setStarted(true);
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSec(realSec.current + 1);
        realSec.current++;
        console.log("ADDED", sec);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{sec}</p>
      <button onClick={setTimer}>X</button>
    </>
  );
}
```